# What does "そんな事なら" mean?

Tags: meaning, translation

I'm reading through the transcript of Madoka Magica episode 5 and came across the line

> そんな事なら、学校休んじゃえばいいのに。

The translation given is "After all that, you should've just stayed home today." So is "そんな事なら" equivalent to "After all" or does it have other meanings?

Comment: Whenever you ask about a こそあど word, it would be best to provide some context.  Without context, we have no idea what そんな refers to.

Comment: It's three expression into one, if you search そんな, 事 and なら individually, you'll probably understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **そんな～**: "such a ～", "～ like that", "～ as it is now"
- **こと**: (refers to the current situation/event at hand)
- **なら**: "if"

So the literal translation is "if such a thing (is happening)" or "if (it's a) situation like that". This is a set phrase that is normally translated like "if that's the case", "if so", "if that's what you mean", etc. "After all that" may be also usable depending on the context (i.e., when there has been a long discussion before this line).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend plugging phrases like this into [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89) to help you get a breakdown.

Like Simon mentioned, it's a combination of three parts:

そんな means "that kind of" and usually comes before a noun to describe a focus on a particular type of that noun.

事｛こと｝ has tons of meanings, but is usually used as a placeholder noun for a situation or event that was mentioned or occurred previously in context.

なら is a conditional device that means the phrase before it is a condition for the following phrase, so XならY is like "if X is true, then do Y"

Putting it all together, it's describing that "if such kind of an event happened, then...". You can see how the translation "after all that, ..." is just a generalization of this phrase.